# How to use Stack Exchange API?

Tags: support, api

I was wondering how to learn to use [Stack Exchange API](http://api.stackexchange.com/)? I know how to program with APIs in my familiar languages, to write html webpages, and to remote control with servers via ssh. But can you tell me what some basic knowledge is needed in order to understand what Stack Exchange API is for and how to use it?

Comment: Belongs on stackapps.com?

Comment: see http://stackapps.com/questions/1/api-documentation-and-help

Answer (score 7):

The best place to go to is:

https://api.stackexchange.com/docs.

This is the latest version which has the information about the APIs having write_access to the sites as well. To start off , i would advise you to work with the javascript example(Javascript SDK) provided by the StackExchange website. Here is the link:

https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/js-lib

Answer (score 2):

Browse http://stackapps.com

And following the [getting-started](https://stackapps.com/questions/tagged/getting-started) tag should get you where you need to be.